# Verifiable Burn/Zero Address

Tags: address, burn

This address came to my attention recently: `tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU` ([tzstats](https://tzstats.com/tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU))

It is an old address (first seen Apr 18, 2020), is advertised as a Burn/Zero address, and funds are regularly sent there by a DEX.

My question is that, unlike other burn addresses (such as `tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX`), this one just looks like a regular address.

What properties of this address make it a verifiable burn address? i.e. provably impossible for someone to hold a corresponding private key

Comment: another oddity is that tzkt reports it as 'first seen' 5 years ago, which doesn't match tzstats data.

Comment: First block that had it in an operation is block of level 913793. (2020-04-17 20:48:41 UTC) 
That operation failed... the balance of tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU wasn't changed (it was the receiver).

The first balance update occurred at block 1571647.

Comment: That address was first seen 5 years ago indeed, at the level 1, where it was specified as a manager for vesting contracts. You can see it here: https://rpc.tzkt.io/mainnet/chains/main/blocks/1/context/contracts/KT1WPEis2WhAc2FciM2tZVn8qe6pCBe9HkDp/manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This address is literally the zero address; it's hexadecimal representation is `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. You can check this by running `octez-client normalize data 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 of type address`.

Comment: Another way to check that: 
```
$ octez-codec encode alpha.contract from '"tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU"'
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```